# VUSB / +5V selector to safely power KNX project

Tags: pcb-design, 5v, 3.3v

I'm working on a board that will include a [TP-UART IC](https://www.hqs.sbt.siemens.com/cps_product_data/gamma-b2b/tpuart.pdf) + an [ATMEGA328-AU](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2047852.pdf) on the same device.

[image]
I'm now facing the potential risk of damaging the host computer or the TP-UART IC if I'm mishandling the power source of the board.

The device can be powered through the KNX bus (typically 30V) and the TP-UART IC has its own built in regulator and will output 5V or 3.3V for an host MCU.

The thing is that I want to be able to power the device from VUSB (when I'm not connected to the bus) and I also want to be able to debug my firmware (so tied to the KNX bus AND the VUSB from the programer / computer)

I've seen some potential solution using P-channel mosfets / some autoswitchinp power mux ([TPS2112](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2112.pdf)) or even just opamp, but I really don't know what would be the safest and if there isn't any risks of back feeding 5V from VUSB to the VCC pin of the TP-UART IC

Edit: @akwky pointed out that if the board is powered by both P1 and VUSB, the internal on-chip regulator may have a slightly different voltage from VUSB. So I edited the schematic by adding a Zener diode Voltage Regulators ([1SMA5918BT3G](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2140502.pdf)) to hopefully clamp the voltage to 5.1V going to VCC/VIF. Maybe I should have put this diode only on PIN 7 of the TP-UART. What do you think?

[image]

Comment: Hi! Are you saying the TP-UART chip will use its internal regulator to provide 5V for your device? I can't seem to find how that would work, from the datasheet. The VIF pin seems like a 5V power input to me (chapter 1.2.7). Can you clarify?
Anyway, why not use just another diode from (an external?) voltage regulator, similar to what you're already doing in `+5V_SELECTOR`?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood the data sheet but the general description say : [...] It generates further a stabilized 3.3V or 5V supply to use by a host controller.[...]

Comment: Also the PIN that output +5V or +3.3V from the onboard regulator is VVSP not VIF (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: You are correct. My apologies, I've missed the description for Vcc and VIF.

Comment: No need to apologies :) I found this particular datasheet incredibly cryptic to be honest...

Comment: I wanted to rectify that the PIN VVSP isn't the output power supply from the "on-chip" regulator as I was previously assuming. The documentation refers to this PIN as "Buffer Voltage VSP / interstate voltage" I'm still having no idea on what this exactly mean but my understanding is that the VSP PIN is just used to hook a bunch of bypass capacitor so the on-chip regulator can still provide a stabilized +5v or +3.3v even when the load on VB+ is changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://www.hqs.sbt.siemens.com/cps_product_data/gamma-b2b/tpuart.pdf), there is no risk to the `TP-UART` if you power through the USB when there's no external power (I assume `KNX` is `P1`). Relevant information is in Section 1.1.1:

[image]

This tells you that there is no damage if \$V_\mathrm{VCC} > V_\mathrm{VSP}\$ and when \$V_\mathrm{IF} \geq V_\mathrm{VCC}\$ respectively. These are the conditions that would be met if you were using \$V_\mathrm{USB}\$ to power the device.

Comment: I found this table really confusing, thanks for confirming me that I can power the chip when there is no external power. But how about connecting it to USB when there is actually power on P1? (to catch serials output for debugging while connected to the bus for instance)

Comment: Yes this is the way the Arduino Nano board protect VUSB from the +5V generated by the on board regulator when using +7V to +20V (VIN input). I thought that using a Schottky will help me avoid getting a low VCC voltage... There might be a better solution

Comment: @Sandra Your protection diode D3 will protect your USB port, so no problem there. One thing, it appears that you don't have `TXD` and `RXD` connected on the TP-USART - is that intentional?

Comment: @Sandra - sorry, I deleted that previous comment as it was wrong (found the datasheet for your actual TP-UART) - see above :)

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, I'm still working on this so some net label are still missing, I'll address this little oopsy in addition to make sure my device will be safe to use / program without having disastrous effects on the end users equipments.

Comment: @Sandra - no problem! Protecting the USB end is preferable, which you've done (diode and fuse). Btw, very nice schematic to go with the question :)

Comment: Thanks you so much! And now I think I'm having a clearer understanding on the 1.1.1 table notes

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding a diode between TP-USART's Vcc (pin 7) and the 5V power rail.

My concern is that if both voltage sources are powered, their voltages will always slightly differ. In extreme case, the VUSB can reach 5.25V, while the TP-USART onboard regulator might deliver only 4.75V. As these are both low impedance paths, large current may flow between VUSB and VCC, causing damage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZUZjw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(I've accidentally burned USB ports once by connecting a USB programmer into an externally powered 5V device.)

Comment: I thought that my fuse would have prevent large current flow between VUSB and VCC when the TP-UART might have a slightly low output voltage, but what you are pointing out make a lot of sense. Any recommendations? I saw that you draw a circuit using 1N4733A Zener diode, should I replace my Schottky diode D3?

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the misleading part number. The only suggestion I was trying to offer was the D10 between Vcc output of the TP-USART and the 5V rail. Using Zeners doesn't make much sense.

Comment: "Using Zeners doesn't make much sense" Now I'm a bit confused :s

Comment: Hi again. I messed up when making the original schematic. I intended to add Schottky diodes, but mistakenly put Zeners in there. Since I can't find symbol for Schottky in the editor, I've now replaced these with normal symbols. I've also changed the part number to match your D3. Using the same part for the D10 should be fine.